# 32-bit XP mode for 64-bit Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-xp-mode

If I install XP mode on my 64-bit Windows 7, will it be 32-bit or 64-bit Windows XP?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [XP-mode FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/faq.aspx) 64-bit is not supported, so it must be 32.

Comment: It is indeed; I've installed it on my laptop this way.

Comment: @Ivo - exactly my thoughts, it's no good to anyone having the same answer multiple times (about as superflous as duplicate questions). however, it's a matter of courtesy to delete your post when someone else posted the same answer BEFORE you and cast an upvote. if you have additional informatio or if you think the answer can be improved otherwise, you can always comment on it or edit the post (if you have enough 'karma'). that's how SU is different from most other forums.

Comment: @heavyd - i said that because you posted your answer after me (only by a minute or two, but later nonetheless) and the second link (to the dev center) appeared even later after a further edit. i commented on your post yet you choose not to delete it. fine by me, in fact, i feel flattered if someone copies my answer but i don't think it is in the best interest of this forum.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that it is 32-bit XP, even on 64bit Win7.  It also runs 16bit programs, which 64bit XP can't do at all.  It allowed the install of a 32-bit "quasi-driver" for my Juniper VPN connection, which would not work AT ALL on x64 Vista/Win7.

On another note, the whole feature is very impressive.  Yes, other VM solutions could do it, but to do it without having to procure an XP license is what makes it the best option for most IMO.  It also requires no real training as 16-bit programs can be executed in XP mode from the Win7 start menu without even bringing up the XP GUI.